# Why do I need parentheses when instantiating a class?

Tags: python, class, instantiation

```
class Human:
    def exist(self)
        return print("exists")

H1 = Human # Why do I need parentheses here? I get error if i dont put parentheses here.

H1.exist() # I get an error that says parameter 'self' unfilled.
```

The class `Human` does not take any arguments, there isn't even an `__init__` method. If I can't give any arguments when making an instance of `Human`, then why do I need parentheses there?

I don't even know what I don't understand but I feel like I am missing something. Probably something about `self`.

Comment: Simply because the syntax of the language requires them. Without them you would assign the class to a new name.

Comment: `Human` is a class, `Human()` instantiates a new object of that class.

Comment: How would you differentiate referencing the class and an instance of the class without them?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes

Comment: Also, there *is* an `__init__` method, you'll be using the base objects instead of your inherited one

Comment: You also need to put `:` after `def exist(self)`. And You probably want to `print("exists")` instead of `return print("exists")` .

Comment: Classes are callable in Python, and their return value is an instance of the class.

Comment: class Human:
    def __init__(self):
        print("human")
>> Human()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In languages where the calling of a function/method/macro takes the form

```
foo(param1, param2, param3)
```

then it is almost universally true that, if `foo` were to take no parameters, the call would be

```
foo()
```

and further that, depending on the language

```
foo
```

is either incorrect, or means something else.

Now lets consider your example, expanded a bit

```
H1 = Human
H2 = Human
H3 = Human
```

In this case, nothing was called. `H1`, `H2` and `H3` have all been assigned the same reference, which is a reference to the class `Human` and not to any *instance* of that class.

```
H1 = Human()
H2 = Human()
H3 = Human()
```

In this case, the class was *instantiated* 3 times, that means that the `__init__` function was run 3 sepearate times, and the result of each is a different *instance* of `Human`. `H1`, `H2` and `H3` now point to three different objects, all instances of `Human`. Since they are instances, they have a `self`.

Answer (score 0):

We need to clarify some points:

1. **To call/invoke a class/function in the major of programming languages you have to use parentheses**
2. **The class/function name simply refers to its object in the memory, therefore without using parentheses we actually referring to the class/function object**
3. **When we use parentheses we actually call/invoke the class/function code and code got executed**